# Intersection between sphere and ellipsoid - number of connected components

Tags: analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $S$ be the unitary sphere of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and for $0<a<b<c$  and $A>0$ let $G(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2 $ and the ellipsoid $E_A$ : $G^{-1}(A)$.

> How many connected components does $\Gamma _A := S \cap E_A$ have ?

I showed that $\Gamma _A $ is non empty if and only if $A \in [a,c]$ and, in this case I want to compute the number of connected components for $A \in ]a,b[ \cap ]b,c[$ of $\Gamma _A$

First of all I showed that for those $A$, $\Gamma _A$ is a one dimensional compact manifold.

It remain to me impossible to count the connected components. Of course a drawing is not an appropriate answer for me...

Another question : I know that the connected components of $\Gamma _A$ are periodical orbits for the EDO : $X'=X \wedge  G(X)$  (or $X'=X \times  G(X)$, US notation) with $X=(x,y,z)$.

> How can I prove that  the period of the solution does not depend of the connected component where X(0) is. (But depend of $A$ of course)

If you have any idea feel free to comment or answer.

Thanks.

Comment: is it about the surface or the volume of objects ? cause for volumes, intersections of 2 convexes gives 0 or 1 connected component.

Comment: about the surface intersection

Comment: When I said the intersection is of dimension 1 it means it's a curve :)